# GMap map and Tabs display conflict in Drupal

Tags: google-maps, drupal, tabs, conflict

I am using **Tabs** and **CCK Fieldgroup Tabs** module to put node **GMap CCK location map** in a tab.
When I put GMap location map in one of the node tabs (Tabs module) other than first one (default), the map view **does not centre properly the marker**. It slides one width off the screen to the east (right). I need to press "scroll right" arrow once on the map controls to have the marker centred properly.

I have read all the Drupal threads touching this issue and all I found are suggestions to **play with resizeMap()** function.
Anyone knows where exactly to play with it? Where to apply the change to the code to accomplish the task in the least invasive way?

Attached screenshots:
[image: Screenshot just after switching to the tab with Gmap map]

[image: After scrolling once marker is in acceptable position]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem was to override tabs ccs styles from drupal-tab.css:

```
.ui-tabs-hide  {
left:-15000px;
position:absolute;
top:-15000px;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

to:

```
.ui-tabs-hide {
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
left: 50%;
top:-15000px;
}
```

in my theme css.
The crucial part is to override left css property of position:absolute.
Works for firefox, safari and google chrome. Not tested in IE as I am sitting on Mac ;-)
If anyone knows better solution for this map display issue please share.